# How to run subshell commands over SSH?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, subshell

I have a cluster of computers which are connected via passwordless SSH and I have written a utility which runs a command over the entire cluster. The way it does it is by picking up machines present in a file, looping over them while running the command specified via SSH.

Now I want to run a kill command over the cluster. The way I do this is by `grep`'ing the process IDs and then running the kill command like this:

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep service_name | awk '{print $2}')
```

But when I run this command, it loops over one machine, executes the command, loops over the second machine and just exits without even executing the command. So the command finally ends up executing on only one machine.

I read about this a bit and found out that subshell commands `cmd1 $(cmd2)` run over SSH don't properly execute.

Can anyone provide me a workaround.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I wrapped the command `kill -9 $(ps -ef | awk "/service_name/{print \$2}")` with a '`' character and ran it using my utility and it worked like a charm. So below is the final command:

```
`kill -9 $(ps -ef | awk "/service_name/{print \$2}")`
```

Comment: @terdon The process that I want to kill is not really registered as a service. `pkill` would still work on it? Suppose I am starting a process like `elasticsearch`, how would I kill it using `pkill`?

Comment: @terdon I am asking this because `pgrep elasticsearch` does not list the `pid` of `elasticsearch` considering `pkill` internally uses `pgrep`.

Comment: `pkill` has nothing to do with whether a process has been "launched as a service" (you mean init scripts?), it is designed to kill any process by name. Read `man pkill` to see how it works. In principle, `pkill elasticsearch` should be enough, as long as the name of the executable is `elasticsearch`. If it doesn't list it, try `pkill -f`.

Answer (score 10):

Actually command substitution, which is not just a subshell, works fine. Your problem is you want it executed on the remote system by the remote shell, because the processes you want to kill are processes on the remote system. So you have to quote it, which gets a bit clumsy, although you can drop the `grep` when you have `awk`. Two options are:

```
ssh user@remote "kill -9 \$(ps -ef | awk '/service_name/{print $2}')"
ssh user@remote 'kill -9 $(ps -ef | awk "/service_name/{print \$2}")'
```

However, a better solution for this problem on most Linuxes and some(?) other Unixes is `pkill` which does the whole job of search for processes running a particular command and kill them:

```
ssh user@remote pkill -9 service_name
```

Depending on how the process is launched, you might need to search against the full command line:

```
ssh user@remote pkill -f -9 service_name
```

Comment: What is the backslash in the first command before $ for?

Comment: @Timo: in the first one it prevents the `$( )` being expanded by the origin shell rather than target shell, and in the second one it prevents the `$2` from being expanded by the target shell rather than awk. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

Comment: so in the first cmd, the backslash leads to the expansion in the target shell, in the second it leads to the expansion of awk second field, not second general arg in target shell? complicated, but well..

Answer (score 6):

Thou shalt not pipe grep into awk!

```
ps -ef | awk '/service_name/ { print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

or

```
pkill service_name
```

Comment: Nice! I used to always pipe grep into awk :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ps -ef | grep service_name | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

You might want to test it first.